choose google account with youtube channel in kotlin
im im trying to create a youtube broadcast in an Android aplication using kotlin.
The problem is that i select the account but the account i want have another channel so the app is trying to put it in the "main" channel, this channel cant perform that action.
If i use the https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert?hl=es-419&apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%7D%7D i see that first i have to select the account and then the channel one with the ability to insert it and the otherone without.
How can i replicate this behaviour? i only made the account picker but dont know how to do the channel picker.
private fun signIn() {
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER)
  }

  private fun setupYouTubeService(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    credential.selectedAccount = account.account
    youtube = YouTube.Builder(
      GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
      JSON_FACTORY,
      credential
    )
      .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
      .build()
  }

  private fun getService(): YouTube {
    if (youtube == null) {
      val transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
      val jsonFactory: JsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
      youtube = YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build()
    }
    return youtube as YouTube
  }
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
      REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER -> if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        data?.let {
          val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
          handleSignInResult(task)
        }
      }
      1 -> if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val selectedImage: Uri? = data.data
        selectedLogoPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage) ?: ""
        // Update UI with the selected logo if needed
      }
      REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION -> if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        CreateLiveBroadcastTask().execute()
      }
    }
  }

  private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {
      val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
      account?.let {
        setupYouTubeService(it)
        CreateLiveBroadcastTask().execute()
      }
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
      Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
    }
  }

